# How to pass parameters from main method to another class

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I pass the parameters from main method to another class?

I have done like this. Is this right approach?

```
namespace classA
{
    class Program
    {

       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string abc= new string {"HELLO"};

            Console.WriteLine("My result: {0}", ClassB(abc));
            Console.Read();

        } 

        public static string ClassB(string abc)
        {

        //code
            return xyz;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work?  Are you having any problems with your solution?

Comment: You need to share the code of another class too. And tell us what you are doing with another class and what issue you are facing .

Comment: You just called another static function with a parameter in your sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in the code you posted you have only one class with two methods but in principle yes, this would be one way:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string abc = "HELLO";
            Console.WriteLine("My result: {0}", ClassB(abc));
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static string ClassB(string abc)
        {
            return abc;
        }
    }
}
```

> My result: HELLO

If you have your second method really in another STATIC class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string abc = "HELLO";
            Console.WriteLine("My result: {0}", myfuncclass.ClassB(abc));
            Console.Read();
        }

    }


    static class myfuncclass
    { 
        public static string ClassB(string abc)
        {
            return abc;
        }
    }
}
```

> My result: HELLO

And if your second method is NOT in a static class and your method is NOT static you have to create an instance of the class first and then call your method on this object:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string abc = "HELLO";
            myfuncclass test = new myfuncclass();
            Console.WriteLine("My result: {0}", test.ClassB(abc));
            Console.Read();
        }

    }

   public class myfuncclass
    { 
        public string ClassB(string abc)
        {
            return abc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I appreciate your explanation.